# Problem uploading sketch to arduino uno/esp8266

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

Getting this error while uploading:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
Executable segment sizes:
IROM   : 236720          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 

IRAM   : 26892   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 

DATA   : 1252  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

RODATA : 780   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

BSS    : 24976 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

Sketch uses 265644 bytes (27%) of program storage space. Maximum is 958448 bytes.

Global variables use 27008 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 54912 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

esptool.py v2.8

Serial port COM3

Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Arsh\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>

    esptool.main(cmdline)

  File "C:/Users/Arsh/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main

    esp.connect(args.before)

  File "C:/Users/Arsh/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect

    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header  
or it says Invalid Head of Packet(0xF0)


_



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

This is the pin configuration:
[image]

Insted of the 3.3v im using a voltage regulator.
Also RX connected to RX & TX to TX.

Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  WiFi.begin("username", "password");

  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {}
```

Someone suggested to ground the GPIO0, didn't work.
Tried installing different version of the Board:"Generic ESP8266 Module" still getting the same error.

The module works fine when working without the library using the Board:"arduino uno"

Comment: io 0 to gnd at reset starts exp8266 in flashing mode. wire RX to RX and TX to TX because the USB chip is already wired RX to TX to the pins

Comment: @Juraj Sorry for the wrong picture didnt look at it very closely. I alredy have RX to RX and TX to TX. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPIO-00 needs to be held at ground while RESET goes to ground, then back to high. This reboots the ESP-01 into the FLASH mode.

For a good overview of a circuit to accomplish this, read:
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/flashing-the-ESP-01-firmware-to-SDK-v2.0.0-is-easier-now/

Read about the ESP8266 boot modes here:
https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap04%20-%20Microcontroller.html

Answer (score 1):

Could you give more details about the 3.3V regulator that you using?
Do you have it connected between the serial signals?

If that is the case, I suggest this connection instead:

[3.3V signal voltage divisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWaJo.png)

ESP TX and Arduino RX can be connected directly without any issue